# How to wait until an array of tasks has finished?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have an array of `Task<T>` objects and would like to block until all have returned.  How would I do this? (This is in a debugging view so performance is not an issue).

Basically, what is the task library equivalent of jquery's $.when?

Comment: Depending on your situation and how the array of tasks were created you might also check out Parallel.ForEach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to block, you can use `Task.WaitAll(yourTasks);`. If you want to use a continuation that fires when they're all done (and are either using .NET 4.5 or the AsyncTargetingPack for .NET 4.0), you can use `Task.WhenAll(yourTasks).ContinueWith(t => ...);`

Comment: Instead of `WhenAll()` combined with `ContinueWith()`, you can use [`Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321258), which is available even in .Net 4.0.

Comment: @svick: Nice catch! Didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Task.WaitAll(arrayOfTasks); ///.....
```